# Installation error with Neo4j enterprise edition 2.0.0

Tags: neo4j

I am a developer at a company. We started using Neo4j recently. We have been using Neo4j community editions till now. We use Amazon as our cloud. We put up the neo database onto cloud and we are using ubuntu instance for this. I was able to put Neo4j community editions onto the cloud till now and put data on it. We have now bought the enterprise edition of Neo4j (Neo4j Enterprise edition 2.0.0) . I am trying to put the new enterprise edition onto the cloud using ubuntu.

I have downloaded the enterprise version and extracted the contents of it on ubuntu. Now I am trying to install Neo database using the command:

**var/lib/neo4j/ neo4j-community-2.0.0 $ sudo ./bin/neo4j-installer install**

This gives me output as:

**WARNING: this installer is deprecated and may not be the optimal way to install        Neo4j on your system.**

**Please see the Neo4j Manual for up to date information on installing Neo4j.
Press any key to continue**

**Graph-like power should be handled carefully. What user should run Neo4j? [neo4j] ubuntu**

**ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/etc/init.d/neo4j-service’: File exists**

**update-rc.d: /etc/init.d/neo4j-service: file does not exist**

This does not install neo database now. The same command was working fine with Neo4j community editions. Please let me know what should be done for this? I am stuck on this for several hours now. I have no clue what should be done.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry you are having problems with this. I recommend using the .deb package if possible. There is a repository at http://debian.neo4j.org/repo and detailed instructions at http://www.neo4j.org/download/linux.

Answer (score 1):

As you are a customer, probably best to open a support ticket, and then add an answer here, so that other people can learn about it?

Did you remove the community installation first? It could be a clash of the two versions.

Because the manual actually says the same thing here:

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-installation.html#linux-install

Comment: Thanks for the response. Ok I will do that. Yes I have removed the community edition before installing the enterprise one.